# String Manipulation - Get the last 'x' amount of chars

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am building a windows explorer app for the web using ASP.NET/C# 3.5. I have a dynamic string that holds my path information. This string changes as you navigate the application. What I am trying to do is get the last “directory name” in my string so for example:

```
C:\Code\AppSettings
```

I would need to return `AppSettings`

If the string was:

```
C:\Code\AppSettings\Backup
```

Then I would need to return `Backup`

I am not savvy enough with string manipulation to get this correctly from a dynamic string. Any help or examples would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: that is easier to do with `Path`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're dealing with file/directory paths, it's best to use the helper methods of the [Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) instead of string manipulation.

You can use the [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
var result = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Code\AppSettings");
// result == "AppSettings"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx). In your case, `Path.GetFileName` would work. Unless there's a trailing backslash. Then you'll need to strip that trailing backslash first.

Or, you can use `Substring` or `String.Split` as others have suggested. However, note that you have to take into account the possibility of that trailing backslash, which can cause trouble with any of the alternatives.

By trailing backslash, I mean a string like `C:\Code\AppSettings\`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Code\AppSettings\Backup")
```

results in `Backup`

The `System.IO.Path` should be used for file or directory path manipulations - it offers plenty of other useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for handling this kind of stuff...

But if you want to it via string handling try

```
string myResult = myString.SubString (myString.LastIndexOf ( "\\") + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
exampleString = "C:\Code\AppSettings\Backup"  
string[] words = exampleString.Split('\\');
```

Tokenises the string according to `'\\'` i.e. will split the string at the `'\'` symbol, into an array containing `C:` `Code` `AppSettings` `Backup`

Then all you would need to do is use the last element in the `words` list however you like.

I've never used `Path` before, but i'm wondering whether it would get what you want, as the last part of the string may be a directory.

Comment: Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to avoid problems caused by paths with trailing directory separators, i.e. "C:\Code\AppSettings\".